Historical - KOH FDE
I'm researching a computer program, KOH, that was installed on the boot sector of a DOS or Windows 3.x PC circa 1995. Was it one of the first examples of full disk encryption?
The program had two nicknames:

Potassium Hydroxide
King of Hearts

Can anyone provide references, documentation, or even first-hand accounts?
Thank you
Updates: used IDEA algorithm, (C) 1995 American Eagle Publications.

This is off topic here as it isn't particularly about the algorithms used. However, you might want to understand that the molecule is written as KOH (potasium = Kalium, Oxide, Hydrogen) , which explains why the first link in Google is this one.

Oh, and here is a rather complete explanation in French, but unfortunately no source code. It mentions the YankeeDoodle virus, now I feel old.

And here a complete book from the author of the virus in where the virus is explained The Giant Black Book of Computer Viruses.pdf. It includes the source code.

Cypherpunks was a very popular mailing list and the archives include a write-up.
The French vxheavens article on Beneficial Viruses is very on-topic and includes screen shots.

As long as you keep to the books about viruses of that author. "Christian Revolutionary" is a slightly less enlightened book. Not that the intro to the virus book isn't scary as heck, but it pales in comparison.
